# Flask-sqlalchemy querying multiple different objects causing timeout

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask / Heroku app that in currently in use. It has been working good, but now due to volume increase there are multiple routes where I have to create a lot of objects from DB. I believe this is what is causing my timeout error. I have moved some of these processes to background tasks, but others, like loading the home screen this is not a good option. I have also tried to add dynos but that did not help. I feel like there must be a more efficient way to do this. Here is an example of one area that is breaking.

```
events=db1.Event.query.join(db1.Event.dates_worked, aliased=True).filter(db1.Worked.date_worked.between (da , da + datetime.timedelta(days = 1))).order_by(db1.Event.items.desc()).all()

c=db1.Customer.query.filter(db1.Customer.purchase_date >= week[6]).all()
d=db1.Donor.query.filter(db1.Donor.monthly_start_date >= week[6]).all()
reps=db1.Rep.query.all()
```

Comment: Are the columns that you are filtering on indexed?